# Add on-click event code to a LabelField

Tags: blackberry, java-me

In my application there is a LabelField with text "www.google.com"  When the user clicks, the default browser should open to www.google.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code

```
final LabelField label = new LabelField("http://www.google.com",LabelField.FOCUSABLE){
            public boolean navigationClick (int status , int time){
                 BrowserSession bSession = Browser.getDefaultSession();
                 bSession.displayPage(label.getText());
                 return true;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score -3):

you may use Jquery.
try this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Opens a link</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="link" id="target">www.google.com</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#target').click(function () {
        var url = $(this).text();
        window.location = "http\://"+url;
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```